# Адаптер для Морского боя - Критика

Tags: android, recyclerview, инспекция-кода

Здравствуйте! Делаю морской бой, расстановку кораблей, для сетки использую `RecyclerView + GridLayoutManager`. Требуется критика по коду, так как придётся его показывать :)

Вот он. Если будут вопросы - готов ответить.

```
public class SetupAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SetupAdapter.AdapterHolder>
{
MoveCallback move_callback;

int four_deck = 1;
int three_deck = 2;
int two_deck = 3;
int one_deck = 4;

int a = 35;
int b = 45;
int c = 55;
int d = 65;

ArrayList<Integer> busy = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Integer> invisibleBusy = new ArrayList<>();

public SetupAdapter(MoveCallback move_callback)
{
    this.move_callback = move_callback;
}

@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView)
{
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}

@Override
public AdapterHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int p2)
{
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.setup_item, viewGroup, false);
    AdapterHolder pvh = new AdapterHolder(v);
    return pvh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final AdapterHolder holder, final int position)
{
    boolean isShip = (position == a || position == b || position == c || position == d);
    boolean isBusy = busy.contains(position);
    boolean invBusy = invisibleBusy.contains(position);
    if (isShip && invBusy)
    {
        holder.setup_choice.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.setup_choice.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    }
    else if(isShip && isBusy){
        holder.setup_choice.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.setup_choice.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    }
    else if(isShip || isBusy) {
        holder.setup_choice.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.setup_choice.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    }
    else holder.setup_choice.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount()
{
    return 100;
}

public void update()
{
    for (int i : busy)
    {
        notifyItemChanged(i);
    }
    for (int i : invisibleBusy)
    {
        notifyItemChanged(i);
    }
}
public void add(int pos){
    busy.add(pos);
    if(isLeftLimit(pos, pos) == View.VISIBLE){
        invisibleBusy.add(pos-1);
        invisibleBusy.add(pos - 11);
        invisibleBusy.add(pos + 9);
    }
    if(isUpLimit(pos, pos) == View.VISIBLE){
        invisibleBusy.add(pos-10);
    }
    if(isRightLimit(pos, pos) == View.VISIBLE){
        invisibleBusy.add(pos+1);
        invisibleBusy.add(pos - 9);
        invisibleBusy.add(pos + 11);
    }
    if(isBottomLimit(pos, pos) == View.VISIBLE){
        invisibleBusy.add(pos+10);
    }
}

public void anchor()
{
    move_callback.onMove(isLeftLimit(55, 65), isUpLimit(55, 65), isRightLimit(55, 65), isBottomLimit(55, 65), true);
    if (four_deck != 0)
    {
        add(a);
        add(b);
        add(c);
        add(d);
        four_deck--;
        a = -1; b = 45;
        c = 55; d = 65;
        update();
        refresh();
        return;
    }
    if (three_deck != 0)
    {
        add(b);
        add(c);
        add(d);
        three_deck--;
        b = 45;
        c = 55;
        d = 65;
        if (three_deck == 0)
        {
            d = -1;
        }
        update();
        refresh();
        return;
    }
    if (two_deck != 0)
    {
        add(b);
        add(c);
        two_deck--;
        c = 55;
        b = 45;
        if (two_deck == 0)
        {
            b = -1;
        }
        update();
        refresh();
        return;
    }
    if (one_deck != 0)
    {
        add(c);
        one_deck--;
        c = 55;
        if (one_deck == 0)
        {
            c = -1;
            move_callback.onMove(View.INVISIBLE, View.INVISIBLE, View.INVISIBLE, View.INVISIBLE, true);
        }
        update();
        refresh();
        return;
    }
}

public void move(int moveDirection)
{
    refresh();
    switch (moveDirection)
    {
        case MoveConstants.LEFT:
            if (a != -1) a -= 1;
            if (b != -1) b -= 1;
            if (c != -1) c -= 1;
            if (d != -1) d -= 1;
            break;
        case MoveConstants.UP:
            if (a != -1) a -= 10;
            if (b != -1) b -= 10;
            if (c != -1) c -= 10;
            if (d != -1) d -= 10;
            break;
        case MoveConstants.RIGHT:
            if (a != -1) a += 1;
            if (b != -1) b += 1;
            if (c != -1) c += 1;
            if (d != -1) d += 1;
            break;
        case MoveConstants.BOTTOM:
            if (a != -1) a += 10;
            if (b != -1) b += 10;
            if (c != -1) c += 10;
            if (d != -1) d += 10;
            break;
    }
    refresh();
    int start = 0;
    int end = 0;
    if(b == -1) start = end = c;
    else if(d == -1) {
        start = b; 
        end = c;
    }
    else if(a == -1){
            start = b;
        end = d;
    }
    else {
        start = a;
        end = d;
    }
    move_callback.onMove(isLeftLimit(start, end), isUpLimit(start, end), isRightLimit(start, end), isBottomLimit(start, end), isOkLimit() );
}

public void refresh()
{
    if (a != -1) notifyItemChanged(a);
    if (b != -1) notifyItemChanged(b);
    if (c != -1) notifyItemChanged(c);
    if (d != -1) notifyItemChanged(d);
}

public int isLeftLimit(int start, int end)
{
    if (start % 10 == 0 || end % 10 == 0)
    {
        return View.INVISIBLE;
    }
    else return View.VISIBLE;
}

public int isUpLimit(int start, int end)
{
    if (start < 10 || end < 10)
    {
        return View.INVISIBLE;
    }
    else return View.VISIBLE;
}

public int isRightLimit(int start, int end)
{
    if (start % 10 == 9 || end % 10 == 9)
    {
        return View.INVISIBLE;
    }
    else return View.VISIBLE;
}

public int isBottomLimit(int start, int end)
{
    if (start >= 90 || end >= 90)
    {
        return View.INVISIBLE;
    }
    else return View.VISIBLE;
}

public boolean isOkLimit(){
    if (a != -1){
        if(busy.contains(a) || invisibleBusy.contains(a)){
            return true;
        }
    }
    if (b != -1) {
        if(busy.contains(b) || invisibleBusy.contains(b)){
            return true;
        }
    }
    if (c != -1){
        if(busy.contains(c) || invisibleBusy.contains(c)){
            return true;
        }
    }
    if (d != -1){
        if(busy.contains(d) || invisibleBusy.contains(d)){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public class AdapterHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    View setup_choice;

    AdapterHolder(View itemView)
    {
        super(itemView);
        setup_choice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.setup_choice);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: В саму логику не вдавался, ибо кода много, но как минимум есть поля `a`, `b`, `c` и `d`, имеющие названия, не раскрывающие их сути. По коду разбросаны магические константы: `45`, `55`, `65`, `100` и т.д. В нескольких местах видны группы `if`-ов и `case`-ов: возможно, их всё же можно как-то объединить и обрабатывать одним `if`-ом в цикле?

Comment: `a` - `d` это дефолтные позиции корабля. Насчёт `if`-ов, вроде нет, а если и да, то кода будет больше)

Comment: Но вы ведь не собираетесь каждому, кто будет смотреть ваш код, рассказывать назначение этих переменных? Оно должно быть понятно по их названию. Насчет `if`-ов - это смотря как переделывать код. Возможно, abcd можно поместить в массив, возможно, ещё что-то. А ещё представьте на секунду, что вам потребуется изменить размеры поля и/или количество и тип кораблей. Ваш код готов к таким изменениям? Это приведёт лишь к изменению некоторых констант или же к доработке доброй половины кода?

Comment: Вы правы, но размер поля не меняется, количество и тип кораблей не меняется, другие названия я придумать не смог, такая мелочь))

Comment: Но вы ведь код написали, наверно, не для реализации самой игры (реализаций которой и так сотни), а для обучения написания правильного кода? Если считаете, что код не должен быть хоть сколько-то гибким - дело ваше. Аналогично с названиями переменных, магическими константами и весьма похожими `if`-ами, которые вполне можно расценивать как дублирование кода. Что с этим всем делать - решать вам. Я своё мнение высказал, и сдаётся мне, что человек, который будет проверять ваш код, упомянет эти моменты.

Comment: Нет, я игру делаю, на готовые реализации не смотрел...

Comment: Я бы еще посоветовал создать модель `BattleField` где были бы все вспомогательные методы типа `isShip()`, не видно матрицы, модель `Coordinate`, `WarShip`, логику игры из адаптера в контроллер `Fragment` или `Activity`, а сам адаптер должен отображать модель `BattleField` и  больше ничего. Можно еще использовать холдеры разных типов, читаемость кода значительно увеличится, вообщем модели, как таковой вообще нет, можно много чего придумать

Comment: По [code-style](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf): открывающая скобка должна находится на одной строке с названием класса/метода/блока; в названиях переменных должен быть выдержан lowerCamelCase; непонятные названия переменных `a`, `b`, `c` и `d`. Может быть имеет смысл сделать инициализацию `ArrayList`'ов ленивой? `return 100` – может быть стоит сделать 100 константой? И еще: в адаптере куча методов – все эти методы относятся непосредственно к адаптеру? Может стоит их вынести в отдельный класс?

Comment: Хух, ну ладно. Спасибо.

Comment: @post_zeew, все связано

Comment: Что за ленивая инициализация?

Comment: Зачем 100 делать константой?

Comment: Ленивая инициализация чего-либо – это инициализация чего-либо в тот момент, когда это в первый раз понадобится, а не заранее. `Зачем 100 делать константой?` – чтобы другим было понятно, что это за магическое число.

Comment: И еще: если Вы заранее знаете первоначальный размер `ArrayList`'ов, то его можно передать в конструктор, дабы сразу выделить необходимую память и не расширять массив позднее.

Comment: @post_zeew первоначальный или максимальный?

Comment: @Flippy, Я думал, что размер `ArrayList`'ов не меняется. Тогда можно и не задавать.